# CakePHP: How can I troubleshoot my Behavior?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, behavior

I have this model at `app/models/product.php`:

```
class Product extends AppModel 
{
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = 'WishList';
    var $actAs = array('Domainable');   


    function beforeFind($query)
    {
        echo "A";   
    }


}
```

Which uses this Behavior at `app/models/behaviors/Domainable.php`:

```
class DomainableBehavior extends ModelBehavior 
{
    function beforeFind(&$model, $query)
    {
        echo "B";   
    }


}
```

When I view a Product page the **A** is echoed but the **B** is not. I get no error.

I don't even think the Behavior is loading at all.

I set the file permissions on `Domainable.php` to `0777` - still not working so not a permissions problem.

I changed the line:

```
var $actAs = array('Domainable');
```

to:

```
var $actAs = array('does-not-exist');
```

I get no difference. No error.

First of all, I do not understand why: if the Behavior is not loaded it would not give me some sort of error message with a reason like: "not found" or "access denied." Is this supposed to generate an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var $actAs = array('Domainable');
```

It needs to be `$actsAs` with the ***s*** instead.

And yes when you use the right variable name it does give an error when it can't find the behavior.